# ActiveRecord query (includes or joins)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, rails-activerecord

I have two classes:

```
class Customer 
    has_many :packages
end

class Package 
    belongs_to :customer
end
```

How can I do a query like this?

```
Customer.includes(:packages).where(packages: 'expires_at < Date.current')
```

With a sample test from console, I got it: `Customer Load (26.0ms)  SELECT  "customers".* FROM "customers" INNER JOIN "packages" ON "packages"."customer_id" = "customers"."id" WHERE (packages.expires_at < '2019-03-13') LIMIT $1  [["LIMIT", 11]]
Traceback (most recent call last):
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (PG::UndefinedFunction: ERROR:  operator does not exist: integer = uuid)
LINE 1: ...INNER JOIN "packages" ON "packages"."customer_id" = "custome...
                                                             ^
HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.
: SELECT  "customers".* FROM "customers" INNER JOIN "packages" ON "packages"."customer_id" = "customers"."id" WHERE (packages.expires_at < '2019-03-13') LIMIT $1
irb(main):003:0>`

Comment: Solved. My customer migration was `create_table :customers, id: :uuid  do |t|` and I added a type: :uuid like this: `create_table :customers, id: :uuid, type: :uuid do |t|`

Answer (score 2):

You can pass the where expression within quotes and bind the value for expires_at.

```
Customer.includes(:packages).where('packages.expires_at < ?', Date.current)
```

Comment: The same, I got this error ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (PG::UndefinedFunction: ERROR: operator does not exist: integer = uuid . Maybe it is because I'm using uuid instead sequential ids.

Comment: That's a different problem. Can you elaborate on that? add the whole error you're getting.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
Customer.includes(:packages).where('packages.expires_at < ?', Date.current).references(:packages)
```

Comment: I got this error `ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (PG::UndefinedFunction: ERROR:  operator does not exist: integer = uuid` . Maybe it is because I'm using uuid instead sequential ids.

Answer (score 1):

```
Customer.joins(:packages).where("packages.expires_at < CURRENT_DATE")
```

or

```
Customer.includes(:packages).where("packages.expires_at < CURRENT_DATE").references(:packages)
```

Comment: Instead waiting code for your query, focus in the error you're getting when applying them @DokNabaku.

Answer (score 0):

**You can do this:**

```
Customer.includes([:packages]).where(["packages.expires_at < ?', Date.today]).references(:packages).order("Customers.created_at desc")
```